# How to convert time data in java?

Tags: java

The following time formats are in outlook calendar file

```
DTSTART;TZID="Eastern":20100728T140000
DTEND;TZID="Eastern":20100728T150000
```

how to convert this time to java time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without tested, look at SimpleDateFormat

```
String ds = "DTSTART;TZID=\"Eastern\":20100728T140000";
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHMMSS").parse(ds.split(":")[1]);
```

Comment: Actually I'd consider it important *not* to discard the timezone info - if the timezones are in a format Java can understand, a more robust approach would be `new SimpleDateFormat("'"'z'"':yyyyMMdd'T'HHMMSS").parse(ds.split("=")[1]);`

Answer (score 3):

This looks like [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar). Take a look at [ical4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html) - a Java API for it.

Answer (score 0):

Handling the timezone will be tricky as "Eastern" is not an actual timezone.  However if you handle that, I would suggest the following SimpleDateFormat will handle the unadjusted parse for you.

```
Date unadjusted = 
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss").parse(line.split(":")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using always SimpleDateFormat:

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"DTSTART;TZID=\"Eastern\":20100728T140000", "DTEND;TZID=\"Eastern\":20100728T150000"};

    for (String string : strings) {
        String dateString = string.replaceAll("(DTSTART|DTEND);TZID=\"Eastern\":", "");
        dateString = dateString.replaceAll("T", "");

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try {
            Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```